# ionic cordova build ios --emulator dont show fail or success build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, xcode10

I've just updated my Xcode to version 10.0 (10A255) and it console too on my macBook. After that i used the command

```
sudo ionic cordova build ios --emulator --prod
```

then it begins to build normally but the build seems like never ends because this process never return a "Build Failed" or "Build successful". It apparently ends suddenly and this is the output in the Terminal:

```
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform ios --target cordova
[16:09:56]  build prod started ... 
[16:09:56]  clean started ... 
[16:09:56]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[16:09:56]  copy started ... 
[16:09:57]  deeplinks started ... 
[16:09:58]  deeplinks finished in 1.52 s 
[16:09:58]  ngc started ... 
[16:10:27]  ngc finished in 28.76 s 
[16:10:27]  preprocess started ... 
[16:10:27]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[16:10:27]  webpack started ... 
[16:10:27]  copy finished in 31.56 s 
[16:14:50]  webpack finished in 263.50 s 
[16:14:50]  uglify started ... 
[16:14:50]  sass started ... 
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[16:14:53]  sass finished in 2.58 s 
[16:14:53]  cleancss started ... 
[16:14:57]  cleancss finished in 3.72 s 
[16:15:51]  uglify finished in 60.77 s 
[16:15:51]  postprocess started ... 
[16:15:51]  postprocess finished in 190 ms 
[16:15:51]  lint started ... 
[16:15:51]  build prod finished in 355.49 s 

> cordova build ios --emulator
Building for iPhone XS Max Simulator
Building project: /Users/usuariomac/WebServer/AppIonicOMT/platforms/ios/OpenMyTab.xcworkspace
Configuration: Debug
Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/usuariomac/WebServer/AppIonicOMT/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/usuariomac/WebServer/AppIonicOMT/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Build settings from configuration file '/Users/usuariomac/WebServer/AppIonicOMT/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
[16:16:41]  lint finished in 49.36 s
```

Before this my project was building normally.
I tried changing the target to a previous iOS version with the command

`ionic cordova build ios --emulator --target "iPhone-X, 11.0" --prod`

but it doesn't worked. And the most stranger thing on this issue is that if i build the app from the Xcode it 'apparently' take the changes that i made in the appp. So , here's my ionic info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.5
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 5.0.13 
Node              : v8.6.0
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/usuariomac/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Any ideas of what is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be related https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

Comment: try `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda it "aparently" worked, at least show build successful, but what this flag do?

Comment: @Eric Yeah seems to be related and the solution is the same. Thanks Guys! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried with

> ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

and it works, but then after generating the .ipa file... this file cannot be installed on the device, giving me the next popup in Xcode

> the entitlements specified in your application’s code signing entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xe8008016).

So i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253833/ios-on-device-unit-testing-fails-to-start-healthkit-entitlements-error) post and tried the next config in XCode.

> Go to Xcode and open the project generated then navigate -> File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System and select "Legacy Build System"

Then i tried again the build command without the build flag and worked as before.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

here also same issue

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h