# HealthKit Authentication Error (Code = 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, healthkit

When I try to authenticate access to write to a user's mindful minutes store (health app) from the onboarding in my own app, the authentication page doesn't display (although I did have this working in previous versions of the app). The app however doesn't crash and there is only the following message in the debugger:

> Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=3 "Failed to look up source with bundle identifier "com.myorg.myapp"" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to look up source with bundle identifier "com.myorg.myapp"}

The code I am using to request the authentication is as follows:

```
let typesToShare = Set([
    HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession)!
])

self.healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typesToShare, read: nil) { (_, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openWalkthroughThree", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I have searched around the internet but can't seem t find anyone with the same issue. I have also checked my entitlements for HealthKit as well as usage description but they both seem to be fine - as I said, I had this working in previous versions of my app.

I would be grateful for any help you could give me in finding a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's going on but simply restarting my device fixed this issue.

Also see: [Missing HealthKit Entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071726/missing-healthkit-entitlement)

Comment: Can confirm. Always worked, stopped working randomly, restart fixed it.